# jQuery(this) weird propagation bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this-pointer

It looks like for some people this question is not clear.

Desired effect:

To remove the class of the element which has the mouse over it.

Problem:

The class removal affects to all the elements with same class even though I'm using jQuery(this) to point to the element.

I have the following html:

```
<div id="stars_rater">
    <span class="wp-svg-star star rater" id = "rater_1"></span>
    <span class="wp-svg-star star rater" id = "rater_2"></span>
    <span class="wp-svg-star star rater" id = "rater_3"></span>
    <span class="wp-svg-star star rater" id = "rater_4"></span>
    <span class="wp-svg-star star rater" id = "rater_5"></span>
</div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
if(jQuery('#stars_rater').length > 0)
{   
    jQuery('.rater').on('mousemove', function(e)
    {
        var parentOffset = jQuery(this).offset(); 
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var number = Number(jQuery(this).attr('id').substring(6));
        var current_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        rating = 0;
        if(relX < (jQuery(this).width()/2))
        {
            rating = ((number-1)+0.5); 
//          jQuery(this).removeClass();
            jQuery(this).addClass('wp-svg-star-1');
            jQuery(this).addClass('star-1');
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine till I get to the commented line. The remove class and following actions are applied to all the elements with class .rater, instead being applied to the jQuery(this).

If I remove this line the script works as expected.

Things I have tried regarding the conflictive line:

```
jQuery('#rater_'number).removeClass('class','');
jQuery(this).attr('class','');
```

Things I have tried for attaching the event in a different way

```
jQuery('#rater_1, #rater_2, #rater_3, #rater_4, #rater_5').on('mousemove', function(e)
```

None of this action have solved the issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/h6zjm76z/ The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: What class are you trying to remove (there is no class called `class`)?

Comment: *"The remove class and following actions are applied to all the elements with class .rater, instead being applied to the jQuery(this)."* That's definitely not happening, with that code, at least not in a single call. It could only happen if this code were called for each of the elements you're seeing the effect on. `jQuery(this)` will definitely, without question, only give you a jQuery instance with that one element in it. (Side note: `removeClass('class')` would remove a class called `class`. I don't see any suggestion in your question that you have one with that name.)

Comment: Do you only have one `<div id="stars_rater">` block per page, or multiple ones?

Comment: That works. If I put inside the if a `alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'))` it throws the different instances.

Comment: This `jQuery(this).removeClass('class'); jQuery(this).addClass('wp-svg-star-1');
            jQuery(this).addClass('star-1');` is the same as a single line of `jQuery(this).removeClass('class').addClass('wp-svg-star-1 star-1');`

Comment: 1 Sorry, the jQuery(this).removeClass('class') was wrong, I have edited the code and removed the 'class'.
2 I know that I can put jQuery(this).removeClass('class').addClass('wp-svg-star-1 star-1') in a single line, but this is not the question and when I try to debug I try to make the code less nested to figure out what is going on.

Comment: I only have one <div id="stars_rater">, regarding the alert, in my case, if I remove the comment and left the line alive, the console also propagates to all the elements.

Comment: @user997593 - fair enough, and I do that also when I run into issues.  Just pointing it out = and why it is NOT an answer.

Comment: Probably NOT a good idea to remove ALL the classes with the `jQuery(this).removeClass();` which is what that does ref: https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ see the last example.

Comment: Because nesting the class additions and removals doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105589/discussion-between-user997593-and-mark-schultheiss).